# Copy specifically selected/non-adjacent cells of a range and paste in same order into another range

Tags: google-sheets

I am surprised this is driving me crazy:
In a Google sheet range, I got a few cells with values I manually selected. The selected cells are in discontiguous - not in an adjacent order (fi. A1, A3, B2, C3). Now I want to copy those cells to another range a few rows below while staying in the same 2-dimensional order (fi. copy to D1, D3, E2, F3).

See this example: [gSheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ATfdhN1HWYNaHrSMajeCcyHyDNqlC2iPwRKc208zIzs/edit?usp=sharing)

How do I do this without using a script?

Answer (score -2):

- press down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and select cells
- right-click on the selected cells and you will enter a special submenu for such actions where you can select **Copy**. unfortunately, you are supposed to install an extension which allows you to do such actions (after clicking on **Copy** this will pop up):

  [image]